# How to keep my buffer when copy, cut then paste a word with Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm facing a simple problem with Vim : 
I would like to copy a word and then cut another to paste the first in the 2nd place

For example :

```
Platea, integer nisi velit!
```

I would like to transform it to :

```
Platea, integer nisi integer!
```

How can i make it the easiest way ? 
If i copy integer with `y` and then cut velit with `d` i can't copy the first word anymore, the buffer contains velit ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

- Yank `integer` (<kbd>yiw</kbd>)
- Visual select `velit` (<kbd>viw</kbd>)
- Paste (<kbd>p</kbd>)

---

Also try `YangRing.vim` plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `yank`ing into a register. For example, with the cursor on `integer`:

```
"xyiw
```

Which will yank `integer` into the `x` register (arbitrary letter), and then after deleting `velit`, you can paste using `"xp`. You can use this with multiple registers as well, so if you need to do an assortment of copy/pastes using the same words in different combinations, it may be useful. I'm sure there will be a more elegant way provided by the Vim gurus, but that should work if you need something to tide you over :)

Answer (score 2):

That's "register", not "buffer", `:help registers`.

Here is a mapping I've had in my `~/.vimrc` for a while:

```
vnoremap <leader>p "_dP
```

It deletes the selected text into the "black hole" register and puts the content of the unnamed register. Easy.

Another option is to use register zero: `"0p`.

Comment: I don't really understand your tips. If i understand it right, i have to copy my word --with  `ye`, then select in visual mode the 2nd word -- `ve` and `<leader>p`. I don't really get the difference btw your solution and the kev's one.

Comment: When you paste `aaa` over `bbb`, the unnamed register now contains `bbb` and you can't paste `aaa` again over `ccc`. This tip adresses this issue. But I think that I misread your question. I didn't saw that you were cutting before pasting and that *that* was the issue. Indeed, `viwp` is the right way to "paste over" in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your vimrc

```
xnoremap p "_dP
```

it will cause pastes in visual mode to delete to the black hole register which will prevent clobbering your yanked content that you wish to paste multiple times.